What, qualitatively, is $\beta$ in $\beta = L \dfrac{u}{u'-u} = Tu \dfrac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}T}$ in evaporation experiments?
What, qualitatively, is $\beta$ in this paper? Why is it a correction term in both specific heat and latent heat measurements?
$$\beta = L \frac{u}{u'-u} = Tu \frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}T}.$$
Relevant excerpts from the paper:

Two general types of experiments were made with this calorimetric apparatus. In the first type (heat-capacity measurements) the calorimeter with a sample of water was heated over a measured temperature range. By making some experiments with the calorimeter nearly full of liquid water and others with it nearly empty of liquid, it is possible to account for the tare heat capacity of the calorimeter, and to obtain the change of a quantity called alpha, $\alpha$, which is a property of the water alone. It previously has been shown in the theory 1 that this quantity, $\alpha$, differs from the enthalpy, or heat content, $H$, of saturated liquid water by another quantity beta, $\beta$. In other words, $$\alpha = H-\beta.$$
The quantity $\beta$ has been shown to be:
$$\beta = L \frac{u}{u'-u} = Tu \frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}T},$$
where $L$ is the heat of vaporization, $u$ is the specific volume of saturated liquid, $u'$ is the specific volume of saturated vapor, $T$ the absolute temperature, and $\mathrm{d}P/\mathrm{d}T$ is the vapor-pressure derivative. In the previous experiments the quantity $\beta$ was measured calorimetrically at higher temperatures, but between $0 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ and $100 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ it is so small that its value can be calculated fom liquid-volume and vapor-pressure data with greater accuracy than can be obtained by calorimetric measurements.


The second type of experiment (vaporization) made with this calorimeter is virtually an isothermal process. Heat is supplied to evaporate a sample of water which is withdrawn from the calorimeter at a controlled rate, collected, and weighed. From this experiment, there is obtained a value of a quantity gamma, $\gamma$, which differs from the latent heat of vaporization, $L$, by the same quantity, $\beta$, mentioned above. In other words,
$$\gamma = L + \beta.$$


The factor $\beta$ is discussed in an earlier paper, Osborne's "Calorimetry of a fluid," defined as a "factor or correction...for fluid evaporated which remains in the calorimeter." The energy portion that goes into latent heating isn't available for sensible heating of the water, which is the phenomenon of interest. So this energy portion is identified and removed as a correction term. The term is also related to the phase-change coexistence line $\frac{dP}{dT}$ through the Clausius–Clapeyron relation.
